# Creating string literals

Tags: arrays, string, c++14

I have a string array. I want to take the n'th word in that array, and print an output like this:

Input: `government`
Output: `g8t`

Basically: `first letter` + `total number of letters-2` + `last letter`

Output is stored in a string array as well.
Here is the basic code that I tried:

```
out[j]=in[j].at(0) + (n-2) + in[j].at(n-1);
//n is the length of word , used str.length() for that
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Please at least tag the language you're using.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch this point **to_string**!!!

A small trial:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<string> words;
string input;
int count = 0;
cout << "Enter 5 words :";

while (cin >> input) 
{
    words.push_back(input);
    if (++count > 4)
        break;
}

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    string str;
    int size = words.at(i).length();
    str = words.at(i).at(0) + to_string(size) + words.at(i).at(size - 1);
    cout << str + "\n";
}

cin>> input;
return 0;
}
```